# Filter recyclerview on firestore realtime data

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, searchview

I am trying to filter my recyclerview using filterable, it works fine on static data, but on dynamic data from firestore

First, I got the data from Firestore in arrayList
Then, I filter those arrayList to new arrayList
But when any change happended in Firestore, the original arrayList will be updated and my recyclerview will display this data instead the data I currently filltered on searchview

What I wanted to do is my recyclerview to aslway display filtered data when I type any word on searchview whether they are any updated data or not

[added screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA8pC.jpg)

> here is my adapter

```
class SearchAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.ListViewHolder>(), Filterable {

    private var listSearch = ArrayList<Dosen>()
    private var listSearchFull = ArrayList<Dosen>()

    fun setData(list: ArrayList<Dosen>){

        this.listSearch = list

        listSearchFull = ArrayList(listSearch)



    }



    inner class ListViewHolder(itemView: UserListBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView.root) {
        private val binding = itemView

        fun bind(dosen: Dosen) {

            with(binding){
                val db = Firebase.firestore
                val collection = db.collection("alat")
                    .whereEqualTo("id", dosen.alat_id)
                collection.get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                        try {
                            val location = document.toObjects(Alat::class.java)[0].lokasi
                            tvLocation.text = location
                        } catch (e: Exception){
                            Log.d("rv", "system error $e")
                        }

                    }
                    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                        Log.d("rv", "get failed with ", exception)
                    }

                tvUsername.text = dosen.nama

                val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd LLLL yyyy")
                val date = simpleDateFormat.format(dosen.datetime!!.toDate())
                Log.d("rvTime", date)
                tvDate.text = date

                val simpleTimeFormat = SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm:ss aaa")
                val time = simpleTimeFormat.format(dosen.datetime.toDate())
                Log.d("rvTime", time)
                tvTime.text = time
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListViewHolder {
        return ListViewHolder(UserListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(listSearch[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = listSearch.size

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return  object : Filter(){
            override fun performFiltering(query: CharSequence?): FilterResults {

                val filteredList: ArrayList<Dosen> = ArrayList()

                if (query == null || query.length == 0){
                    filteredList.addAll(listSearchFull)

                } else{
                    val searchQuery = query.toString().toLowerCase().trim()

                    for (item in listSearchFull) {
                        if (item.nama!!.lowercase(Locale.ROOT).contains(searchQuery)){
                            filteredList.add(item)
                        }
                    }
                }

                val filterResults = FilterResults()
                filterResults.values = filteredList

                return  filterResults


            }

            override fun publishResults(query: CharSequence?, filteredResult: FilterResults?) {
                //error
                listSearch.clear()

                listSearch.addAll(filteredResult!!.values as ArrayList<Dosen>)
                notifyDataSetChanged()

            }

        }
    }
}
```

> and here is my fragment

```
class SearchFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentSearchBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var searchAdapter: SearchAdapter

    private lateinit var searchArrayList : ArrayList<Dosen>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentSearchBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        searchArrayList = arrayListOf()

        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        eventChangeListener()

        return root
    }
    private fun eventChangeListener() {




        val db = Firebase.firestore
        db.collection("presensi")

            .orderBy("datetime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
                override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
                    searchArrayList.clear()
                    for (document in value!!){
                        searchArrayList.add(document.toObject(Dosen::class.java))
                        searchAdapter.setData(searchArrayList)
                        Log.d("arraySearch", document.toObject<Dosen>().toString())
                        Log.d("arraySearchList", searchArrayList.toString())
                    }
                    searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }

            })



        searchAdapter = SearchAdapter()

        with(binding){
            tvNoData.visibility = View.GONE
            rvSearch.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            rvSearch.setHasFixedSize(true)
            rvSearch.adapter = searchAdapter
        }
    }


    /// prob need fix
    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        menu.clear()
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        val searchView = context?.let { SearchView(it) }
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).apply {
            setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW or MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM)
            actionView = searchView
        }

        searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {

                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                searchAdapter.filter.filter(newText)

                return false
            }

        })

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Log.d("firebaseFirestoreListener", "onStart")
    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
        Log.d("firebaseFirestoreListener", "onDestroyView")
    }


}
```

Is it actually possible to do what I want?
or should I use 3rd party library like algolia, but it's not free.

I hope you guys understand my question

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: 1st, I got the realtime data from firestore and store it in an arrayList `listSearch`.  2nd, I create another arrayList `listSearchFull` which contain all value of `listSearch`. 3rd, I filter the value on `listSearch` using `filterable` for searching name function. 4th, while I filter the list, it works just fine. 5th, but when the are any data change in firestore(add or change) while I filter the list, the list will go back to all data available until I type in the seachview again (check my screenshot I just added).

Comment: If you understand Java, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) will help.

Comment: does the app in your article stays in the filtered list even tho any data being updated in firestore?

Comment: You can check the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9d8T6QCB96E).